# CSS cover if browser window is larger than 1138px × 825px

Tags: html, css

So I'm programing a site and the body bg image is set to background-image:cover. It works fine but there is one issue. My background image is 1138px × 825px and I want it to stay at those dimensions if the browser window is smaller than 1138px × 825px. I want the image to act like a regular background image and not shrink. When the browser is open larger than 1138px × 825px I want the css cover feature to kick in. I have tried applying min-height/min-width and height/width but to no prevail. Any ideas or solutions? Thanks a lot in advance. Site and CSS code are below.

Site: test.baysidemarket.com

CSS code:

```
#home{
background:url('imgs/back01.jpg') no-repeat top left fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
width: 1000px;
height: 725px;

}
```

html:

```
<body id="home">
</body>
```

Comment: The conditionals you need in this case are only possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that in css is with the

```
@media (min-width: 1138px) and (min-height: 828px){
// your code for larger display
}
```

Comment: I noticed on mobile development, many phone/tablet browsers disregard the `@media` tags sadly :( It would require a lot of testing to be sure if it works on each browser/platform as intended.

Comment: I'm not sur of that because bootstrap use it for responsive display and until now everything works well

Comment: I just hope so for Brian's sake ^^

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but this should logically work:

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    var body_w = $('body').css('width').replace('px', '') * 1;
    var body_h = $('body').css('height').replace('px', '') * 1;
    console.log(body_w + 'x' + body_h);

    // Initial check
    if (body_w > 1138 && body_h > 825) {
        $('body').css({
            '-webkit-background-size' : 'cover',
            '-moz-background-size' : 'cover',
            '-o-background-size' : 'cover'
            'background-size' : 'cover'
        });
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var body_w = $('body').css('width').replace('px', '') * 1;
        var body_h = $('body').css('height').replace('px', '') * 1;

        if (body_w > 1138 && body_h > 825) {
            $('body').css({
                '-webkit-background-size' : 'cover',
                '-moz-background-size' : 'cover',
                '-o-background-size' : 'cover'
                'background-size' : 'cover'
            });
        }
        else {
            $('body').css({
                '-webkit-background-size' : 'auto',
                '-moz-background-size' : 'auto',
                '-o-background-size' : 'auto'
                'background-size' : 'auto'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It does an initial check if it should use `cover` and check again when the window get's resized.

Don't forget to remove the initial CSS `background-size`, as it's not needed anymore.

```
#home{
    background:url('imgs/back01.jpg') no-repeat top left fixed;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 725px;
}
```

Note: If possible, try to upgrade your jQuery. I see you use 1.7.2, try using 1.9.x

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! Looks like Javascript is going to be the solution.